# RecyclerView: Last item getting cut off when returning back to the activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a `RecyclerView` inside a `CoordinatorLayout` with `CollapsingToolbar`

I'm experiencing a weird behavior of the last item in the `RecyclerView` getting cut off when returning back to the activity. I found a solution but it involves changing the scrollflags which would make the toolbar not pin on the top, which is not what I wanted. I removed all `fitSystemWindows=true` and tried setting the `RecyclerView`'s height to `wrap_content` but still to no avail.

What can I do to fix this?

#### layout.xml

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/collapsing_toolbar_collapse"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/white"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom|left"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/margin_medium"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/collapsing_toolbar_expanded"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/height_toolbar_expanded" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/toolbarBack"
                    layout="@layout/layout_back" />

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_medium">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView37"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_xx_small"
                android:fontFamily="@font/carrois_gothic"
                android:text="@string/pos"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_medium"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView40"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_xx_small"
                android:fontFamily="@font/carrois_gothic"
                android:text="@string/points"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_medium"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView41"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/carrois_gothic"
                android:text="@string/player"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_medium"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline12"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/leaderBoardListBg"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:background="@drawable/shadow_gradient_bottom" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: same problem here, found any solution?